# rotate text in the table while coverting html into pdf(wkhtml) in java

Tags: java, html, pdf

I am trying to convert html into pdf(wkhtml). My html code is given below

```
public static String generateReportNewPDF(String reportName, List dataList, List<Field> fields, List<SelectOption> inputCriteria, List<String> outputColumnsList, ReportModel reportModel){
        StringBuffer reportHTMLContent = new StringBuffer();
        String data;

        try{
            reportHTMLContent.append("<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" id=\"listHeader\">");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<tr><td>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<div style=\"text-align: center; padding: 8px 5px; color: #333333; position: relative;\">");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<span class=\"grey14pixel\" style=\"font-size:22px\"><b>"+ApplicationConfig.getProperty("government_english")+"</b></span>&nbsp<br/>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<br><span style=\"font-size:18px;\">"+reportName+"</span>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("</div>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("</td>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("</tr>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<tr><td>&nbsp;</td>   </tr>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<tr><td>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"5\">");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<tr>");

            reportHTMLContent.append("");

            int row = 1;
            for(SelectOption se : inputCriteria){
                if(null!=se.getId() && !se.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("template")){
                    reportHTMLContent.append("<td width=\"10%\" align=\"right\" valign=\"top\">"+se.getId()+"  :</td>");
                    reportHTMLContent.append("<td width=\"10%\" style=\"color:#0055AA;\" valign=\"top\">"+se.getValue()+" </td>");
                    if(row % 5 == 0){
                        reportHTMLContent.append("</tr><tr>");
                    }
                    row++;
                }
            }



            reportHTMLContent.append("</tr> </table>    </td>   </tr>   </table>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("</tr> </table>    </td>   </tr>   </table>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\"><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>");

            reportHTMLContent.append("<table style=\"transform: rotate(-90deg)\" border=\"1\" id=\"example\" class=\"display\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\">");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<thead>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<tr>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("</tr>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<tr>");

            reportHTMLContent.append("<th colspan=\"6\" align=\"centre\" style=\"width:10%\"><b>ലഭിച്ചതും നടപടി എടുത്തതുമായ തപാലുകളുടെ എണ്ണം</b></th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th colspan=\"7\" align=\"centre\" style=\"width:10%\"><b>ഫയലുകളുടെ തീർപ്പാക്കൽ</b></th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th colspan=\"12\" align=\"centre\" style=\"width:10%\"><b>വളരെ പഴക്കമുള്ള ഫയലുകളുടെ അപഗ്രഥനം</b></th>");

            reportHTMLContent.append("</tr>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<tr>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th align=\"left\" style=\"width:15%\"><b>S. No.</b></th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th align=\"left\" style=\"transform: rotate(-90deg)\">സെക്ഷൻ</th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th align=\"left\" style=\"width:15%\">മുൻമാസത്തിൽ ലഭിച്ചതും എന്നാൽ നടപടി എടുക്കാതെ ശേഷിച്ചതുമായവ</th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th align=\"left\" style=\"width:15%\"><b>തൻമാസം ലഭിച്ചത്</b></th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th align=\"left\" style=\"width:15%\"><b>തൻമാസം നടപടി എടുത്തത്</b></th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th align=\"left\" style=\"width:15%\"><b>കൈകാര്യം ചെയ്തവയുടെ ശതമാനം</b></th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th align=\"left\" style=\"width:15%\"><b>തൻമാസം ആരംഭിച്ച പുതിയ ഫയലുകളുടെ എണ്ണം</b></th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th align=\"left\" style=\"width:15%\"><b>തൻമാസം തീർപ്പാക്കിയ പുതിയ ഫയലുകളുടെ എണ്ണം</b></th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th align=\"left\" style=\"width:15%\"><b>തീർപ്പാക്കലിന്‍റെ ശതമാനം</b></th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th align=\"left\" style=\"width:15%\"><b>തൻമാസത്തിൽ ‌തീർപ്പാക്കാനുണ്ടായിരുന്ന പഴയ ഫയലുകളുടെ എണ്ണം</b></th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th align=\"left\" style=\"width:15%\"><b>തൻമാസം തീർപ്പാക്കിയ പഴയ ഫയലുകളുടെ എണ്ണം</b></th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th align=\"left\" style=\"width:15%\"><b>തീർപ്പാക്കലിന്‍റെ ശതമാനം</b></th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th align=\"left\" style=\"width:15%\"><b>തൻമാസത്തിൽ ‌തീർപ്പാക്കാനുണ്ടായിരുന്ന പഴയ ഫയലുകളുടെ എണ്ണം</b></th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th align=\"left\" style=\"width:15%\"><b>കാൾ ബുക്കിൽ ചേർത്ത ഫയലുകളുടെ എണ്ണം</b></th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th align=\"left\" style=\"width:15%\"><b>മുൻമാസം</b></th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th align=\"left\" style=\"width:15%\"><b>തൻമാസം</b></th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th align=\"left\" style=\"width:15%\"><b>തൻമാസം തീർപ്പാക്കിയ ഫയലുകളുടെ എണ്ണം</b></th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th align=\"left\" style=\"width:15%\"><b>തീർപ്പാക്കലിന്‍റെ ശതമാനം</b></th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th align=\"left\" style=\"width:15%\"><b>മുൻമാസം</b></th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th align=\"left\" style=\"width:15%\"><b>തൻമാസം</b></th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th align=\"left\" style=\"width:15%\"><b>തൻമാസം തീർപ്പാക്കിയ ഫയലുകളുടെ എണ്ണം</b></th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th align=\"left\" style=\"width:15%\"><b>തീർപ്പാക്കലിന്‍റെ ശതമാനം</b></th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th align=\"left\" style=\"width:15%\"><b>മുൻമാസം</b></th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th align=\"left\" style=\"width:15%\"><b>തൻമാസം</b></th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th align=\"left\" style=\"width:15%\"><b>തൻമാസം തീർപ്പാക്കിയ ഫയലുകളുടെ എണ്ണം</b></th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th align=\"left\" style=\"width:15%\"><b>തീർപ്പാക്കലിന്‍റെ ശതമാനം</b></th>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("<th align=\"left\" style=\"width:15%\"><b>തൻമാസം മലയാളത്തിൽ കൈകാര്യം ചെയ്ത ഫയലുകളുടെ എണ്ണം</b></th>");
            /*for(Field field : fields){
                for(String outputColumn : outputColumnsList){
                    reportHTMLContent.append("<div>");
                    if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(outputColumn) && outputColumn.equalsIgnoreCase(field.getText())){
                        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(field.getFieldColumnStyle()))
                            reportHTMLContent.append("<th  style=\"width:15%\" style=\""+field.getFieldColumnStyle()+"\"><b>"+outputColumn+"</b></th>");
                        else

                            reportHTMLContent.append("<th style=\"width:15%\" > <b>"+outputColumn+"</b></th>");
                            reportHTMLContent.append("</div>");
                    }
                }
                if(null!=field.getRequired() && field.getRequired().equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                    reportHTMLContent.append(customColumnName(field.getText(), field, reportModel));


                }
            }*/

            reportHTMLContent.append("</thead>");
            reportHTMLContent.append("</tr>");
            /*reportHTMLContent.append("</table>");


            reportHTMLContent.append("<table id=\"example\" class=\"display\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\">");*/
            reportHTMLContent.append("<tbody style=\"display: table-row-group;vertical-align: middle;font-size:13px\"\">");


        return reportHTMLContent.toString();
    }
```

Table is so lengthy. so i didnt get the full table, only half of the page will display. So i planned to rotate the text in 90 deg. Width will reduce and portion will displayed. I write the code

```
style=\"transform: rotate(-90deg)\"
```

But its not working .Can you Please help me

Comment: and why not the pdf in format landscape?

Comment: pdf is in ladscape only, But table is too lengthy and the only way is reduce the width. Is there any idea?